# Python Combobox same piece of code in 2 places works and fails

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, tk-toolkit, ttk

I've run into weird problem with Python tkinter. The program itself is over 500 lines and will be even more, but I will post relevant pieces.

System configuration:

PyCharm 2019.1.3 Build #PY-191.7479.30
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.60 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Core of the problem: same piece of code accessing same global variables runs correctly in one place and totally fails in another places for what seems to me no reason at all.

I have a combobox (an array of comboboxes, to be precise) that takes one of the two values: "CC" and "CV".

```
ModeChosens[i] = ttk.Combobox(pinSettingsFrames[i], textvariable=dropdownVarModes[i],width=5)
ModeChosens[i]['values'] = ("CC", "CV")
ModeChosens[i].grid(row=1,column=4)
ModeChosens[i].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", ModeChanged)
```

When I submit the form, I can easily get the selected value as:

```
if(ModeChosens[k].get()=="CV"): 
     finalnumber=int(extractedNumericValue)
else:
     ...
```

This piece of code executed correctly. IT WORKS. Always. I know I'm not actually using textvariable, but this works the way it is, I tested it.

But I want to perform action as soon as specific combobox value is selected. The problem is that

```
    def ModeChanged(event):
         print(dropdownVarModes[i].get()) #get value from var
         print(ModeChosens[i].get()) #get value directly from combobox
```

I even passed the array pointer as an argument now in my debug attempts assuming I take value of some other combobox from the array of comboboxes

```
def ModeChanged(k):
    print(dropdownVarModes[k].get()) #get value from var
    print(ModeChosens[k].get()) #get value directly from combobox
ModeChosens[i] = ttk.Combobox(pinSettingsFrames[i], textvariable=dropdownVarModes[i],width=5)
ModeChosens[i]['values'] = ("CC", "CV")
ModeChosens[i].grid(row=1,column=4)
ModeChosens[i].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda h: ModeChanged(k=i))
```

Same result! Always "CC"!

Any hint would be highly appreciated, thank you.

The function that is supposed to tell what is selected is EXACTLY the same as above, but it returns the default value all the time, no matter what I picl. Same get function in the same app. In one place it executes correctly, in another place it returns wrong value. I've spent some time googling how to implement action on combobox selection, there aren't many solutions, almost all of them suggest my way of implementing it with bind, but, as you see, it doesn't work, and I have no clue why.

Comment: Could you post [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: My program prints "CC" after I click the combobox "CC" option, and it prints "CC" after I click "CV". What kind of example should I provide?